# ReactNative (expo): How to display audio waves in the mobile application?

Tags: react-native, audio, expo, waveform

I want to have a little player in my application with vizualizer of audio waves, but any library doesn't work me. React native have only a few libraries for it, but they are too old. Do anyone know good library or some native method for it?

https://github.com/juananime/react-native-audiowaveform
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-wave-visual

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.